# MSI installer, using .exe without msi

Tags: windows-installer, setup

I'm using a MSI installer to create a setup for my application, and it generates 2 files, .msi and .exe. Now i know that the .exe is just a bootstrapper that actually runs the .msi, but my questions is if there is a way to reduce these 2 to one file only? (I wouldn't like to use zip to store both, like i currently do)

Also, i cannot use the .msi only because it has no "Run as Administrator" option, which is needed in this case. If i try to open the .exe only, i get the "Unable to locate application file '_____.msi'."

Comment: MSI installers usually request elevation only when really required. Are you sure you need something different?

Answer (score 0):

it all depends on what Setup Installer software you are using.

I have experience working with Advanced Installer and Installshield and in there you can define the final form of your build : msi , exe or both.